# Using python2.7 with Emacs 24.3 and python-mode.el

Tags: python, python-2.7, emacs, emacs24

I'm new to Emacs and I'm trying to set up my python environment. So far I've learned that using "python-mode.el" in a python buffer `C-c C-c` loads the contents of the current buffer into an interactive python shell, apparently using what `which python` yields. In my case that is python 3.3.3. But since I need to get a python 2.7 shell, I'm trying to get Emacs to spawn such a shell on `C-c C-c`. Unfortunatly I can't figure out, how to do this. Setting `py-shell-name` to what `which python2.7` yields (i.e. `/usr/bin/python2.7`) does not work. How can get Emacs to do this, or how can I trace back what Emacs executes when I hit `C-c C-c`?

Comment: I think you may need something like this, which I use for latex:  `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))` -- of course, you would place your own path to your python stuff instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python-mode.el, execute a python buffer using python2:

`M-x py-execute-buffer-python2`

or put this in .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
    '(py-force-py-shell-name-p t)
    '(py-shell-name "python2"))
```

python-mode.el checks `py-force-py-shell-name-p` variable when executing `py-execute-buffer`(bound to `C-c C-c` key), and if this variable is set to true("t"), then use python interpreter name saved in `py-shell-name`.

Alternatively, this customization can be done in `M-x customize`, Programming>Languages>Python Mode, search there for "Py Force Py Shell" and "Py Shell Name" lines.
It will add this customization code to your .emacs file.

Emacs help(describe function):

`C-h f py-execute-buffer TAB`

You can send selected region in a python buffer to any interpreter:

`C-u 3 M-x py-execute-region`

Emacs will prompt every time for a python interpreter name you want to use.
The prefix numerical argument may be any number except 1 or 4, otherwise it will use a default interpreter without prompt.

To execute a buffer in different python interpreters you can select whole buffer by `C-x h` and then use this prefixed command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use python, but from the source to python-mode, I think you should look into customizing the variable `python-python-command` - It seems to default to the first path command matching "python"; perhaps you can supply it with a custom path?