# change emacs python-mode interpreter to python3.5

Tags: python-3.x, emacs

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144901/python3-interpreter-for-emacs-instead-of-2-7) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588464/using-python2-7-with-emacs-24-3-and-python-mode-el) with no success, in both cases when I `C-c C-p` I still get python2.7..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the python interpreter that emacs is using with the command

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")
```

you should set it to whatever the command is that you want. It can also be ipython in which case you would need

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i")
```

where the `ipython` command calls the python 3.5 version of ipython

Answer (score 2):

The above solution did not work for me. What did work was:

(setq py-shell-name "python3")

According to py-choose-shell in python-mode.el, it chooses the shell via the following methods:

This does the following:

- look for an interpreter with `py-choose-shell-by-shebang'
- examine imports using `py--choose-shell-by-import'
- look if Path/To/File indicates a Python version
- if not successful, return default value of `py-shell-name'